# js library that can do the psycopg2.extras.execute_values()

Tags: javascript, python, psycopg2

My question is if it's possible or if there is a js library that can do the psycopg2.extras.execute_values() or it's python specific

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: More to the point `execute_values` is `psycopg2` specific.